# What does "floated and noted" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does "floated and noted" mean? I have no context to present.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you add a complete sentence, in context, where you heard this?

Comment: Can you consider that offering no context is close to asking what does voted and bloated mean?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/215927/yosef-baskin no

Comment: [***floated and noted***](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/lucky_duck.html) = *uttered and recorded*. Not that it has any significant currency, but for native speakers in any likely context, the intended *(**facetious**)* meaning should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it would relate to the idea of ‘floating’ a concept, meaning raising it for discussion. Therefore “floated and noted” could mean ‘raised and considered/accepted’. It’s not a common expression for sure

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion - can you cite examples of why your answer reflects common usage?

Comment: "noted" does not mean "accepted".